# control volume by javascript function

Tags: javascript, android

I have to play a music file on HTML page which is running on `android`, also need to control the volume by javascript function. Can someone give me any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the HTML5 `<audio>` element, you can control the volume using the `.volume`. attribute. Set it to `1.0` for max volume, and `0.0` to mute it.

For example, this script will begin playing a file, then reduce its volume to 25% after a few seconds.

```
  <audio src="http://goo.gl/89jWZ" id="example"></audio>
  <script>
    var audioElement = document.getElementById("example");
    audioElement.play();

    setTimeout(function() {
      audioElement.volume = 0.25;
    }, 3000);
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. it's working but only on window, Not on android. any idea about it.

Comment: Oh, damn. Apparently the attribute isn't widely-supported, I didn't realize. Sorry, I have no further advice.